# New Chrome behavior: clicked element stays where it is and document scroll position moves when new content loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've notice a new behavior only on Chrome that is effecting all of my AJAX "load more" functions, accordion type content reveals, and other effects.

### Desired effect:

- more content is loaded or hidden content is shown
- the scroll position on the page stays exactly where it is, content below the position where something new was added moves down
- the button or element you clicked may move downward on the page - possibly out of the viewport - which is the intended effect for a "show/hide" or "load more posts" button.

[image: placeholder content is displayed and hidden with a show/hide button and jquery - normal behavior]

This is how is still works on Firefox, Safari and how it used to work on Chrome.

### New Chrome behavior

- the button or element clicked stays exactly where it is and the entire page scroll position moves around it.

[image: placeholder content is displayed and hidden with a show/hide button and jquery - Google Chrome behavior example]

Why did this change get implemented, and is there an easy way to force the old behavior?

Here's my extremely basic demo for proof of concept / testing:

```js
$('.toggle-me').hide();

$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.toggle-me').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.toggle-me {
  background: #ffeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div><div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div><div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div class="toggle-me">Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</div>
<div><button id="toggle">show/hide</button></div>
<div>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</div>
<div>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow-anchor` css property

```js
$('.toggle-me').hide();

$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.toggle-me').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
div {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.toggle-me {
  background: #ffeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div><div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div><div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div class="toggle-me">Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</div>
<div><button id="toggle">show/hide</button></div>
<div>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</div>
<div>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
```

Comment: Wow, nice. This CSS only answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, this solves the visual problem without removing focus from the button or taking the user out of natural tab order. `document.activeElement` still returns the button after clicking in this solution.

Comment: thanks again for this answer - makes for a 1 line CSS fix instead of having to muck around in dozens of js files.

Answer (score 1):

"Why did this change get implemented" can't really be answered by SO

"and is there an easy way to force the old behavior?"
I doubt it, if that's the way they want Chrome to behave - it doesn't seem like it would be a toggle-able feature.

But as a *workaround* you could put the show/hide button *above* the "fold"

```js
$('.toggle-me').hide();

$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.toggle-me').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.toggle-me {
  background: #ffeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div><button id="toggle">show/hide</button></div>
<div class="toggle-me">Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</div>
<div>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</div>
<div>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
```

Comment: Sure - this workaround works if you can change your layout and HTML. But the example is just a proof of concept for an issue that represents a more complex and pervasive issue throughout all of our projects. Look at the AJAX load more button behavior at the bottom of http://stockbridgeucc.org/sermons/ for example in Chrome vs Firefox. In Firefox more posts load and you can "continue" scrolling down to check them out. In Chrome you now hardly notice that anything new loaded because your scroll position stayed with the button and the content loaded above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Chrome is keeping the element in view if it is still the focused element. That makes sense in most UI contexts, but in others it does not. I'm guessing the change was made for accessibility reasons and I don't want to try and circumvent good accessibility. But I think in some contexts it's not a good behavior.

Examples where it does not make sense:

- User reads through 2 paragraphs of text and must click on a button to reveal the next 5 paragraphs of text. In this case the page position should stay the same and the content should load downward so the user can "keep reading".
- Typical AJAX "Load More" button. Same logic as above. If a user has scrolled down a list of 20 product tiles and they press "load more" to get the next 20, they should be able to "pickup where they left off" not be forced to the bottom.

So the solution in these cases is just to blur the element before loading the content.

```js
$('.toggle-me').hide();

$('#toggle').on('click', function(){

  // use blur here only if appropriate for your UI context
  $(this).blur();
 
  $('.toggle-me').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.toggle-me {
  background: #ffeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div><div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div><div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div class="toggle-me">Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</div>
<div><button id="toggle">show/hide</button></div>
<div>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</div>
<div>Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
<div>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</div>
```

Comment: So simple and this seems to handle everything (so why have a bounty?) and now I'm curious about a non-jQuery problem/solution, for example when the button press simply toggles a class on the div and CSS does the animation.

Comment: I added the bounty before I spent hours figuring it out... :(  Still open to other solutions. jQuery was just a quick way to get the example up and running. I don't think it's a jQuery specific issue.

Comment: I created a sample on my local machine in an html file which amounts to doing `.classList.toggle('hidden');` on the div (where .hidden has display:none) — click the button the div appears when the _hidden_ class is removed ... here's the weird part: in Chrome when browsing that test page it behaves as desired, showing the text and pushing the button downward, but putting the same thing here in a snippet it leave the button in place and pushes the text _up_, leaving the pointer still on the button. _It depends on the scroll position_. The snippet has a smaller window.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it's trying to make sure a focused element does go out of view, which I guess makes sense. So if the animation won't push it out of the view port it acts one way, and it it will, it acts another way...